# I have released a latest version of my android app, but people are not updating. What should I do to make them download? FCM or in app messages?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-in-app-messaging

I have released a latest version of my android app, but people are not updating.  What should I do to make them download? FCM or in app messages?

Answer (score 0):

Try to make both of them: FCM and in-app messaging.
I think the most important will be the content of your message.
You have to be convincing enough to teach the value of your update to the user so that he will perform the required action.

Don't forget to make that your main action (both for the notification and the in-app message) should redirect the user to the GooglePlay page of your app.

Also, watch your target to target only users who don't have yet the latest app version.

However, if your update doesn't bring too much important change from the user point of view. I will recommend you to go only with in-app messages so that only people that are still interested by your app will be notified about it.
Unneeded notification can be disturbing especially if you plan to send it recurrently until the user effectively update.